# Can you wash an inner tent in the washing machine?

Tags: camping

Can you? The inner tent incorporates its own groundsheet. Will this get damaged? It has mould on it from being in storage.

It's a Vango Tempest 200, 2013 model (they look different now).

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Vango-TEGTEMPESP09151-Tempest-200-Tent/dp/B0061JMKLG

Comment: This might be more suited for [outdoors.se] Stack Exchange

Comment: +1 @Midavalo.... or [option B: consult the manufacturer](http://www.vango.co.uk/gb/content/25-faqs) How do I clean my tent or treat mould?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the manufacturers FAQs have the answer [How do I clean my tent or treat mould?](http://www.vango.co.uk/gb/content/25-faqs)

Comment: Just because the manufacturer advises something, doesn't mean it is the only option, or the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can machine wash the inner tent, in cold water and with a mild detergent.  It will remove the active mold and mildew, but might not remove mildew stains in the fabric.

European style washers are better than the American style with the center aggitators.

Or you can set it up and hand wash it.  A bit more work, but then whose fault was it that the tent was packed away wet  ;-)

Comment: For the record, it got mouldy in the loft. But yeah, that seems like the low risk option :)